# Bash script variable not string

Tags: string, bash, variables

```
#!/bin/bash

testFunction () {
read -p "Question" $1
echo $1
}

testFunction foo
```

My intention is for read to assign the user input to the variable in the argument, and then echo it out, however instead of echoing user input it echos `foo`.

I realize to get around this I can use [Bash indirection](http://www.enricozini.org/2008/tips/bash-indirection/) like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

testFunction () {
read -p "Question" $1
echo ${!1}
}

testFunction foo
```

However, I would prefer to avoid using this method since not all languages have variable indirection (and I will be moving onto a new language soon enough). Is there any other way I can make it look at `foo` as if it was a variable? Thanks.

Comment: Do you really believe that other languages will support any other forms of indirection that could be used in bash?

Comment: Well, if they don't then, how would this problem be solved in another language?

Comment: what's the point of all of this? why do you do it?

Comment: Although I find that slightly irrelevant to my question, I'll humor you by saying that it's a for a yes/no function I've made (since I had several yes/no functions in my program). I want the yes/no function to be able to check if the user input is equal to [Yy] or [Nn] and then act accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any language that has a `eval`-like construct it is possible to interpret a string as a variable name. In Bash:

```
eval echo \$$foo
```

In Python:

```
from __future__ import print_function
eval ( "print (" + foo + ")" )
```

In most languages that lack `eval` this is not possible.

Comment: Thank you for the input, as Python is actually the next language I will be learning.

Comment: But you wouldn't do it that way in Python regardless; you'd use a dict.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I would do (based on your comment):

```
testFunction () {
  read -p "yes or no? [YynN] "  bla
  if [ "$bla" = 'Y' -o "$bla" = 'y' ]; then
      return 0
  fi
  return 1
}

if testFunction; then
  echo "it was yes"
fi
```

or

```
testFunction () {
  read -p "yes or no? [YynN] "  bla
  if [ "$bla" = 'Y' -o "$bla" = 'y' ]; then
      echo 1
  else
      echo 0
  fi
}

foo=`testFunction`
echo $foo
```

Comment: I still need to dynamically define what variable read will store user input in as opposed to having a fixed variable (bla).

Comment: you're still trying to do it at the wrong place. if you do want to do it in the function you **have to** use indirection.

Comment: Tangentially, the conditional can be made more elegant using `case` than this `if [` construct.

Answer (score 0):

You do can do this with `eval`

```
testFunction () {
    eval 'read -p "Enter Y or N: " '$1
    eval 'echo $'$1
}

testFunction foo
```

But `eval` is not a tool to be used lightly. What you're doing is probably crazy. You should be using an approach like this

```
testFunction () {
    read -p "Enter Y or N: " bar
    case "$bar" in
        [YyNn]) return 0 ;;
    esac
    return 1
}

testFunction && foo=valid
```

This way you don't have to re-check `$foo` later, its value is an answer to the question "Was the input valid?"

But maybe you want, later, to actually do something different based on whether the user said `y` or `n`, which I suspect is what drives this "Let's dynamically create a variable from a function" nonsense. In that case you can do something like

```
testFunction () {
    read -p "Enter Yes or No: " bar
    case "$bar" in
        [Yy][Ee][Ss]|[Yy]) printf y ;;
        [Nn][Oo]|[Nn]) printf n ;;
    esac
}

foo=$(testFunction)
```

This is functionally similar to the `eval` version, but it assures that you only get known values into `foo`. Later you can test the value in `foo`.

```
if [ -z "$foo" ] ; then
        echo invalid input
elif [ "$foo" = "y" ] ; then
        echo answered yes
elif [ "$foo" = "n" ] ; then
        echo answered no 
fi
```

And you can keep this code simple, because all possible values are already known.

Comment: Make more sense to return 0 for yes and 1 for no, maybe loop on invalid input, but that depends a lot on the application - for a reusable function, provide an option.

Comment: @tripleee: Agreed on all points, but I question the value of completeness and correctness for contrived examples which are as speculative as this. Given a clearer request I'd provide a better answer.